# Find out the row which I want in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table like follow:

```
   id  primary key, 
   list_id int,  
   item_id  int, 
   created  timestamp.
```

now, I want to find out the row's list_ids  which after I group by item_id, and fetch the row with the highest created in every group. What sql query can do this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by highest created, you'd mean the latest record that is created?

If that's so, you may do a `SELECT` statement and use this in your `WHERE` clause to look for the latest created record

```
WHERE created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should give the item_id and max created_at date for that item_id:

```
select item_id, max(created) from table group by item_id;
```

Comment: sorry , I think i don't describe the question precisely.   I have edit the question , which I want to find out was the max create in the group.